# controller to view array transfer error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a array in my controller and i am loading a view and transferring array to it

my controller function is this

```
public function do_search()
{
    $exp=$this->input->post('expert');
    $records=$this->do_search_md->search($exp);
    //debug($records);die;
    if (!empty($records)) 
    {
    $this->load->view('new',$records);
    //$this->load->view('header');
    //$this->load->view('getdr1',$records);
    }
    else
    echo "error";
}
```

$records is my array.. i have a function in my debugger helper

```
debug($records);
```

its working fine
giving result like this
[image]

but when i am loading getdr1 view... it says $records is UNDEFIND!!!

Comment: In CodeIgniter, data you are going to load in a view, would be set as an individual variable. E.g: `$data['records'] = $records; $this->load->view('some_view', $data); // In view, you can use $records`

Comment: what is the code at view file , are u printing $records teir , if yes then change it to $new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
$records['record']=$this->do_search_md->search($exp);
```

In your view

```
print_r($record);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in an array like this and then load:

```
$data['records'] = $records;

$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter passes multi-dimensional array from controller to views.

Your code should be:

```
$data['records'] = $records;
$this->load->view('new', $data);
```

So that, in view, frameworks [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) `$data` and you get `$records`

The array `$records` you are looking for should be the key of `$data`.

Comment: That is the old out dated links now. ellislab does not deal with codeigniter new and old user guide links now here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs